# Can't add lines to diamond shape created with only CSS

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me to make this logo using CSS?

[Image of the logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72E7K.png)

First I made a square with width and height and then I tried using pseudo elements but I get stuck because I can only use two times pseudo elements,one before and one after so I can't do it with that approach.

This is the code from the second approach but as you can see this method is not really good because it's not quite reusable and the lines are not aligned when you zoom in. [JSFiddle of the code below.](https://jsfiddle.net/2earwuf6/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}

.first-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-top: 3px solid yellow;
}

.second-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <title>Web Design | Mike Taylor</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Main header -->
  <section class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <div class="first-line"></div>
        <div class="second-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- End Main header -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* 1170px container */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.rectangle {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
}

.first-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  border-top: 3px solid yellow;
}
.second-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
.third-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(177%) translateX(81%) rotate(90deg);
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
.forth-line {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-115%) translateX(81%) rotate(90deg);
  border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Web Design | Mike Taylor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Main header -->
    <section class="main-header">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="rectangle">
          <div class="first-line"></div>
          <div class="second-line"></div>
          <div class="third-line"></div>
          <div class="forth-line"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End Main header -->
  </body>
</html>
```

full page screenshot

[image]

Comment: You can see on fullscreen that your solution also has the same problem,the upper left and bottom right line are not properly positioned,they are going too much inside .

Comment: @webdevst1 check edited screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Check the below answer hope it helps you

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.rectangle {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.rectangle h1 {
   margin: 0;
    line-height: initial;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: arial;
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    padding: 40px;
}
.rectangle:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background: yellow;
    right: -60px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

.rectangle:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 60px;
    height: 4px;
    background: yellow;
    left: -60px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.rectangle .line:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 4px;
    background: yellow;
    top: -60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
.rectangle .line:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
    width: 4px;
    background: yellow;
    bottom: -60px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
}
```

```html
  <section class="main-header">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="rectangle">
        <div class="line">
        <h1>M</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: This is good logic but it isnt responsive,when I need an icon inside or bigger font it doesnt act responsive.

Comment: @webdevst1 answer updated please check, 
If you increase font size it will be working fine but if want to add more text then you have to do adjust the padding

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one div idea without complex code:

```css
.logo {
  --b:5px; /* adjust this to control the thickness */
  /* control the size */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /**/
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -100%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) center/100% var(--b), 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) center/var(--b) 100%, 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) center/50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) center/calc(50% - 2*var(--b)) calc(50% - 2*var(--b)),
    linear-gradient(#fff 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
  mask-composite: exclude;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">M</div>
```

Another idea:

```css
.logo {
  --b:5px; /* adjust this to control the thickness */
  /* control the size */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  /**/
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
.logo:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: -100%;
  padding:70%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: 
    linear-gradient(90deg,#fff 25%,#0000 0 75%,#fff 0) 50%/100% var(--b), 
    linear-gradient( 0deg,#fff 25%,#0000 0 75%,#fff 0) 50%/var(--b) 100%,
    conic-gradient(from  90deg at top   var(--b) left   var(--b),#0000 90deg,#fff 0) content-box,
    conic-gradient(from -90deg at bottom var(--b) right var(--b),#0000 90deg,#fff 0) content-box;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
body {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">M</div>
```